# Does convergence in the $r$th mean for all $r$ imply almost sure convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, lp-spaces

Almost sure [convergence of a sequence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) and convergence in the $r$th mean (for any $r$) each imply convergence in probability. However, (I believe) neither of them implies the other for fixed $r$.

What about convergence in the $r$th mean for *all* $r$? This implies almost sure convergence, correct?

Comment: Convergence in $L_{\infty}$ is not equal to convegence in $L_r$ for all $1 \le r < \infty$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. You're right; edited to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative.

Consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Put $A_1 = [0,1]$, $A_2 = [0, \frac12]$, $A_3 =  [\frac12, 1]$, $A_4 = [0, \frac14]$. $A_5 = [\frac14, \frac12]$, $A_6 = [\frac12, \frac34]$, $A_7 = [\frac34,1]$, $A_8 =[0,\frac18]$ and so on. Put $f_n = I_{A_n}$. Hence $f_n \to 0$ in every $L_r$, $r \ge 1$ and $f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ (or anywhere else) a.s.

Comment: Does convergence in $L_\infty$ imply convergence a.s. (or vice versa)?

Comment: @tparker Convergence in $L_\infty$ implies convergence a.s. but not vice versa.

Comment: @Ian Interesting - so convergence in $L_\infty$ is stronger than both convergence a.s. and convergence for all $L_r$, which are incomparable, and both are stronger than convergence in probability?

Comment: @tparker There are some minor ambiguities with that sentence that make me hesitant to simply answer "yes". In detail, convergence in $L_\infty$ is the strongest of the bunch. Convergence a.s. does not imply any convergence in any $L_p$ nor vice versa. The convergences in $L_p$ in a probability space are "monotonic" i.e. convergence in $L_p$ implies convergence in $L_q$ if $p>q$. All of the above imply convergence in probability.

Comment: @Ian Great, thanks so much. Is there a simple example of a sequence that converges a.s. but not in $L_\infty$? (I can make that a new question if you'd prefer.)

Comment: @tparker Sure; let the probability space be $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and consider $X_n(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [0,1/n] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Comment: @Ian Got it. Am I correct that, roughly speaking, convergence a.s. is analogous to pointwise convergence in functional analysis, while convergence in $L_\infty$ is analogous to uniform convergence?

Comment: @tparker They are basically the same concepts; a.s. convergence is "pointwise convergence ignoring a null set" and $L_\infty$ convergence is "uniform convergence ignoring a null set".

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, because of the following lemma (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4)):

> If $(X_n)_n$ converges in probability to $X$, and if $\mathbb{P}\{|X_n| \leq b\} = 1$ for all $n$ and some $b$, then $(X_n)_n$ converges in $r$th mean to $X$ for all $r \geq 1$.

In particular, this applies to the bounded sequence $(X_n)_n$ with $X_n$ being a Bernoulli with parameter $1/n$. But converges in probability to $0$, yet not almost surely.